# Printing multiple lists in one string

Tags: python

I have two separate lists of users (a person's name) and email addresses.  How do I modify this

> message = """To:
>
> Hey,
>
> How is the weather?"""

to print without changing

> print(message)

Basically I'm looking for it to print out something similar to this without modifying the print(message).

> To: bob@gmail.com
>
> Hey, Bob
>
> How is the weather?

I'm sorry if this sounds dumb, but I feel like I'm just beating my head against a wall here and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Start by familiarizing yourself with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: You can google for string formatting: `'To: {}'.format(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.format()` as a means of string interpolation.

```
email = "bob@gmail.com"
name = "Bob"

message = """To: {}
From: {}
How's the weather""".format(email, name)

print(message)
```

The above code will output:

> To: bob@gmail.com
>
> From: Bob
>
> How's the weather

Comment: OK I tried it and got this as an error: ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 19))

Comment: It sounds like you are reading some kind of input from a file or the command line for your email and name variables. Could you post the code you are using to do that

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of achieving the desired result

```
email = "bob@gmail.com"
user = "Bob"

message = """To: {} \nFrom: {} \nHow is the weather?""".format(email, name)

print(message)

To: bob@gmail.com 
From: Bob 
How is the weather?
```

But I think you may be interested in the `input` function that creates a text box and you fill it. Here is how it works.

```
input('Do you want to write a message? : ')
input('Tell us who is receiving the message: ')
input('Now write your message in this box: ')
```

Here are the answers that I put in ['Yes', 'John', 'Hi John, this is Samuel Nde.']. The output is below.

```
Do you want to write a message? : Yes
Tell us who is receiving the message: John
Now write your message in this box: Hi John, This is Samuel Nde.
'Hi John, This is Samuel Nde.'
```